# Solving limit with unknown exponent without L'Hopital

Tags: calculus, limits, limits-without-lhopital

I came across this limit and it was told that we should not use L'Hopital's rules for this one:

$$
\lim _{x\to 0\:}\left(\frac{\left(1+x\right)^a-1}{x}\right)
$$

I can't see a way to get around that x on the denominator, I can't expand the binomial because it's an unknown.. Any solutions? Is it even possible without L'Hopital?

Comment: Use the derivative definition $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{f(1+x)-f(1)}{x}$

Comment: Are you not using binomial theorem because you don't know whether $a \in \mathbb N $ or not. Right?

Comment: @JaideepKhare exactly

Comment: Have you heard of squeeze theorem?

Comment: Then let me edit my answer.You can use extended binomial theorem dor any $a \in \mathbb R$

Comment: @bthmas not in this context.. Sorry guys I'm pretty new to calculus.

Comment: If you are new to calculus, it is best to prove the result for rational $a$ using the techniques of algebraic manipulation or if you are adventurous enough you can take inequalities / Squeeze Theorem approach also. The case for irrational $a$ has to be deferred till the time when you have understood the theory of exponential and logarithmic functions (see Dr. MV's answer which uses this).

Comment: Also note that this limit is in form of derivative so using L'Hospital's Rule here is kind of very roundabout.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We will evaluate the limit using only standard inequalities and the squeeze theorem.  To that end, we begin with a short primer.

---

> **PRIMER ON STANDARD INEQUAITIES**
>
> In [THIS ANSWER](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1589429/how-to-prove-that-logxx-when-x1/1590263#1590263), I showed using only the limit definition of the exponential function and Bernoulli's Inequality that the logarithm and exponential functions satisfy the inequalities
>
> $$\frac{x-1}{x}\le\log(x)\le x-1 \tag 1$$
>
> for $x>0$ and
>
> $$1+x\le e^x\le \frac{1}{1-x}\tag 2$$
>
> for $x<1$

---

First, note that we can write $(1+x)^a=e^{a\log(1+x)}$.  Then, using $(1)$ and $(2)$ we find that for $ax<1$

$$\frac{a}{x+1}\le\frac{(1+x)^a-1}{x}\le \frac{a}{1-ax}\tag3$$

whence applying the squeeze theorem to $(3)$ yields the coveted limit

> $$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{(1+x)^a-1}{x}=a}$$

Comment: Oh, I see it now! Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome!  My pleasure and pleased I could help you.  -Mark

Comment: +1 This was the approach I was alluding to in my comment.

Comment: @bthmas Thank you; much appreciative!  -Mark

Comment: I think this is a very suiting answer because that uses things that i've seen in the course thanks again @Dr.MV

Comment: Caio, that's great!  I'm glad that this is fit for purpose.

Answer (score 1):

**Use binomial theorem for any index.**

$$(1+x)^a=1+ax+\frac{a(a-1)}{2!}x^2+\frac{a(a-1)(a-2)}{3!}x^3+\frac{a(a-1)(a-2)(a-3)}{4!}x^4 .....$$

$$\implies \lim _{x\to 0\:}\left(\frac{\left(1+x\right)^a-1}{x}\right)=\lim _{x\to 0\:}\left(\frac{\big(1+ax+\frac{a(a-1)}{2!}x^2+ \ldots)-1}{x}\right)$$

$$=\lim _{x\to 0\:}\left(a+\frac{a(a-1)}{2!}x+\ldots \right)=\boxed a$$

$\big($ Here $|x| <1$ and $a \in \mathbb R$  $\big)$

Comment: OP says he cannot use the Binomial th.

Comment: @caverac He said because he is not sure whether $a$ is an natural number, I am saying to use for any index

Comment: It's much easier to read this quotient as a rate of variation.

Comment: @CaioPetrelli See this.This can be used for *any* $a$.

Comment: @JaideepKhare I can't really see how that makes it easier..

Comment: @CaioPetrelli See now.

Comment: @JaideepKhare Oh, I see it. That's a very beautiful approach.. I would never seen that, thanks!

Comment: The binomial theorem for any index is proved using that limit in question. So this is kind of circular.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever there's $h \to 0$ on the denominator, you should think of the derivative. You have written the derivative of $y \mapsto (1+y)^a$ at $y=0$, which you can easily calculate by the chain rule.

Comment: I see where you're coming from but unfortunately I'm still looking at limits as being just limits. I'm still early in the course! But thanks that made me appreciate the simplicity of things!

Answer (score 1):

Let $z=x+1$, then $x\to 0$ as $z\to 1$, and for change of variable:
$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{(1+x)^{a}-1}{x}=\lim_{z\to1}\frac{z^{a}-1}{z-1}$$
Using the fact that $a^{n}-b^{n}=(a-b)\left(\displaystyle\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}a^{n-1-i}b^{i}\right)$, therefore:
$$\lim_{z\to1}\frac{z^{a}-1}{z-1}=\lim_{z\to1}\frac{(z-1)\left(\displaystyle\sum_{i=0}^{a-1}z^{a-1-i}\right)}{z-1}=\lim_{z\to1}\left(\displaystyle\sum_{i=0}^{a-1}z^{a-1-i}\right)=\displaystyle\sum_{i=0}^{a-1}\lim_{z\to1}z^{a-1-i}=\sum_{i=0}^{a-1}1=a$$
As desidered.

Comment: $a$ is not necessarily a positive integer.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case you want to see another approach, using
$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{e^x-1}{x} = 1$$ and $$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\ln(1+x)}{x}=1$$
Therefore, $$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{(1+x)^a-1}{x} = \lim_{x\to0}\frac{e^{\ln(1+x)^a}-1}{\ln(1+x)^a}\cdot\frac{a\ln(1+x)}{x} = a$$